Lebesgue differentiation theorem: existence.
The Lebesgue derivative of $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the limit of $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt$ as $r$ vanishes. My question is the following: does this limit exist for every $x$?
The proofs I saw only focus on almost everywhere type of arguments since they are concerned with the identity of the limit with $f(x)$, which can only hold modulo a negligible set. But if we consider the limit for itself, without comparing it to $f(x)$, how can we show, at least in $\mathbb{R}$, that it always exists? Perhaps it doesn't?

It doesn't always exist. Here is an example of a measurable set $A$ whose density at $0$ doesn't exist; if you consider its characteristic function then its derivative at $0$ doesn't exist. Basically make sure that as we zoom in around $0$, the proportion of $A$ alternates wildly. Take a sequence of increasing integers $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}>10^{2n}a_n$, so $\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}<\dfrac{1}{10^{2n}a_n}$. Let
$$\displaystyle A=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{a_n},-\frac{1}{10^na_n}\right)\cup\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{10^na_n},\frac{1}{a_n}\right)$$
The proportion of $A$ in the interval $(-\frac{1}{a_n},\frac{1}{a_n})$ is larger than $1-10^{-n}$, but the proportion in the interval $(-\frac{1}{10^na_n},\frac{1}{10^na_n})$ is smaller than $10^{-n}$.

For those interested, it was recently mentioned in the mathoverflow thread How large can the set of turbulent points be? that this "maximally extreme" behavior of Lebesgue density (lim-inf is $0$ and lim-sup is $1)$ can occur at each point of a set with Hausdorff dimension $1.$ Of course, the set in question has Lebesgue measure $0$ since Lebesgue density exists at all but a Lebesgue measure zero set of points.
